# Cannot open Pdf files from website server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, fedex

I am doing MVC ASP.NET website in which I have to integrate FedEx shipping.
I have to open a PDF at the end of the process which is creating in shipping process. But it's not opening in website server. It's working perfectly in local. My code is given below. please help me

```
private static void SaveLabel(string labelFileName, byte[] labelBuffer)
        {
            // Save label buffer to file
            FileStream LabelFile = new FileStream(labelFileName, FileMode.Create);
            LabelFile.Write(labelBuffer, 0, labelBuffer.Length);
            LabelFile.Close();
            // Display label in Acrobat
            DisplayLabel(labelFileName);
        }

  private static void DisplayLabel(string labelFileName)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(labelFileName);
            info.UseShellExecute = true;`enter code here`
            info.Verb = "open";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info);
        }
```

Comment: any error which you are getting. also the path should be absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

It will now work on website. 
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start is used to run the perticular program on the system. you are running the program on server, so file will be open on the server not on the browser.
Its wrong approch for opening pdf files in browser.

Right approach is return action type as File or FileStreamResult:

```
public FileStreamResult PDFGenerator()
{ 
    ///byte[] labelBuffer  generate the buffer from pdf  
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
     ms.Write(labelBuffer, 0, labelBuffer.Length);
     ms.Position = 0;
     return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");
}
```